# Alinhar imagens e texto dentro de div

Tags: html, css

Preciso alinhar alguns elementos em uma página e não estou conseguindo, já fiz alguns testes como usar o `text-align:center` na classe `pull-right` bem como na `header-features` de acordo com exemplos que li, mas sem sucesso.

O que tenho é isso:

```
 <!-- ALINHA CONTEÚDO -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
     <!-- CLASSE ONDE O CONTEÚDO ESTÁ -->
      <div class="pull-right">
        <ul class="header-features">
          <li><i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i>
            <div class="header-feature-caption"> <img src="img/caixa.jpg" width="108"> </div>
          </li>
          <li><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right"></i>
            <div class="header-feature-caption">
              <h5 class="header-feature-title">ANUNCIAR IMÓVEIS</h5>
              <p class="header-feature-sub-title">clique aqui</p>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

E o css deles são esses:

```
.pull-right {
  float: right !important;
}

.header-features {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

O que estou tentando fazer é isso:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O projeto pode ser visto aqui:
[Página Demonstração](http://topdeia.com.br/projetos/index-m.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que visualizei você está trabalhando com Bootstrap, faça um teste: apague a div do pull-right e coloque a class pull-right na tag UL e para garantir, em seu col-md-12 acrescente também a classe: text-right

E me dê um retorno aqui se funcionou!

Comment: Se o site estiver em algum arquivo online, passa o link por favor, pq posso experimentar as alterações e lhe passar algo concreto, caso as instruções acima nao funcionar!

Comment: Olá @Gabriel Garcia, acabei de colocar on-line, estou meio confuso nessa alteração, se puder me ajudar agradeço.

Comment: eu havia entendido errado, achei que quisesse alinhar na direita, no caso vc que no centro neer?

Comment: Isso mesmo @Gabriel Garcia, no centro, como na imagem postada como exemplo.

Comment: Obrigado @Gabriel Garcia, ficou exatamente como preciso, grande ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Faça o seguinte:

```
<div class="col-md-12">

          <center>

            <ul class="header-features">
              <li><i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i>
                <div class="header-feature-caption"> <a href="http://www1.caixa.gov.br/atendimento/canais_atendimento/correspondente_caixa_aqui.asp" target="_blank"><img src="img/correspondente-caixa.jpg" width="108"></a> </div>
              </li>
              <li><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right"></i>
                <div class="header-feature-caption">
                  <h5 class="header-feature-title">ANUNCIAR IMÓVEIS</h5>
                  <p class="header-feature-sub-title">clique aqui</p>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </center>

</div>
```

Pelo menos eu fiz aqui no meu navegador e deu certo.

Retire a  classe pull-right nao precisará dela, e no lugar da div dela coloque o o `<center>`